# Magento Top Menu suddenly stops writting "Active" Class

Tags: css, magento, php

I have come accross a strange problem where magento seems to have stopped writting the Active and Active parent classes onto my menus.

I have been using the default Magento menu and it has been working for a month or so fine. I have cleared the cache and re-indexed the categories and products.

Any advice appreciated.. could this be a file permision problem ?

Comment: Disable block html caching entirely and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed Benmarks advice, Disabled the Block Html Caching and the active class was being written again.

Answer (score 3):

for me this xml change in my local.xml solves the issue:

```
<default>
    <reference name="catalog.topnav">
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_lifetime</key></action>
        <action method="unsetData"><key>cache_tags</key></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento's HTML Block caching is a rather strange beast. They've only enabled a few blocks to work with it, one of which is the top menu (the template file is different depending on which version of Magento you're using).

If you want to keep block caching on and get rid of this bug, then you could create a module with a new block type which

```
extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
```

and set the following data in your block's `_construct()` method:

```
$this->addData(array(
   'cache_lifetime'    => null,
   'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG),
));
```

This sets the cache time to null, ie disables it.

Then, in your layout files you'll need to find (in `page.xml`) the Navigation Bar. It will have the following tag:

```
<block type="catalog/navigation"...
```

Which you'll need to replace with your own module's navigation block class:

```
<block type="mycompany/navigation"
```

Refresh your caches, and you should find your classes behave properly. For more information on Magento's layout I really reccommend Alan Storm's excellent book ['No Frills Magento Layout'](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout), and for a great addition to your Magento debugging tools check out [this module](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/magento-advanced-template-hints.html) which shows you which blocks are being cached (as well as a whole load of other useful block info).